# Why won't my git push recognize changes in the codebase?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I committed  some changes.

`git diff` correctly shows  differences between my branch and `origin/master` on Github (for Pages).

Yet `git push` shows "Everything up-to-date."

(See full interaction below).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ git fetch
$ git status 
On branch mybranch1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git diff origin/master 
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 2791a21..ef702c5 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -4,11 +4,8 @@
...[More changes here, diff is abbreviated.]
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: yes, as shown by git status and the git diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with that push command you are not pushing mybranch1 into master.... you are pushing your **local** master branch into the remote master branch. Try this:

```
git push origin mybranch1:master
```

Comment: Bingo! Also,  git push  origin HEAD:master will do it.

Comment: Yes.... or just saying `git push` if you set up the upstream branch for mybranch1 to be origin/master.